# memsql show slow performance response using order by

Tags: singlestore

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM scheme.table cont WHERE game_id = 'some-game-id' AND event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59' ORDER BY event_arrival_time
```

I get response time of almost 30 seconds

for the same query if I remove `ORDER BY event_arrival_time` i get the response in few seconds

This is the create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `cont_event` ( `event_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `action` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `correlation_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `status` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `event_arrival_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `create_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `create_ts` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, `operator_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `game_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `player_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `segment_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `bet_amount_original` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `bet_amount_converted` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `cont_amount_player` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `cont_amount_operator` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `cont_amount_total` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `operator_income` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `cont_amount_jackpot` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL, `original_currency` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `base_currency` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `currency_rate` decimal(20,6) DEFAULT NULL, `operator_game_code` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `funnel_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `segment_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `operator_game_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `extra_fields` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, `jackpot_game_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `game_version` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL, `event_type` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, `event` JSON COLLATE utf8_bin, KEY `operator_id` (`event_arrival_time`,`action`,`operator_id`,`game_id`,`correlation_id`) /*!90619 USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE */ /*!90618 , SHARD KEY () */ ) /*!90621 AUTOSTATS_ENABLED=TRUE */
```

i do have index on: `event_arrival_time, action, operator_id, game_id, correlation_id`

when doing memsql profile i can see the filter works fine(see attached):

[image]

iam not sure what am I missing? any suggestions for optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your first query repeated:

```
SELECT *
FROM scheme.table cont
WHERE
    game_id = 'some-game-id' AND
    event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
    event_arrival_time
```

The index you have currently defined looks either wrong to me, or at least sub-optimal.  Try the following index instead:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON cont (event_arrival_time, game_id);
```

Ideally, MemSQL would be able to scan the above index, in the order of the event arrival time, in the range you defined, and retrieve all matching records.

Comment: thanks for your response. is that the syntx to create index? because I get parse error on my database? as I read Columnstore indexes cannot be created after the table was created. i need to re-create the table right? perhaps I forgot to mention iam using Columnstore

Comment: i just modified my prev comment that iam using Columnstore database on memsql. iam not sure i can create such indexes on already created table? (according to this ref: https://docs.memsql.com/v6.5/reference/sql-reference/data-definition-language-ddl/create-index/)

Comment: If that's the case, and you really need to tune your first query, then you may have to recreate the table with a new (more appropriate) index.

Comment: so how would you try to create the table with the coumnstore database index? although I thought having such index will still be applied to sub-indexes out of the box. i mean i have event_arrival_time, action, operator_id, game_id, correlation_id as an columnstore index so have where clauses with only with event_arrival_time and game_id should have worked no?

Comment: I'm not an expert in MemSQL, but assuming the index being created here would be some sort B-tree variant, then your current index may not be optimal.  You want one of two things here, either an index which can cover the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, which my answer gives you, or an index which can do this _and_ also cover the `SELECT` clause.  I didn't go for the latter, because if what I suggested doesn't help, then a covering index might also not get very far.

Comment: the thing here is that this is a columnstore index and iam not sure if it's behaving like a rowstore index